How to split an HTML string around tags?
How can I use Python to split an html string by a specified unpaired tag? For example
split('hello<br    >there', 'br')

should return ['hello', 'there'],
split('<div id="d71">text1<br data-i="1">text2<br>text3</div>', 'br')

should return ['<div id="d71">text1', 'text2', 'text3</div>'] or ['<div id="d71">text1</div>', '<div id="d71">text2</div>', '<div id="d71">text3</div>']
I've had a look at
def get_start_stop(source, tag_name):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
    return dir(soup.find(tag_name))

But the things I was hopeful about, sourcepos, string, strings, self_and_descendants, .nextSibling.sourcepos don't have the information necessary (as far as I can tell) to get the start and end indexes of the tag in the source string.
I've also tried things like
from lxml import html

def split(input_str, tag_name):
    tree = html.fromstring(input_str)
    output_list = []
    for element in tree.iter():
        if element.tag == tag_name:
            output_list.append(element.tail)
        else:
            output_list.append(html.tostring(element, encoding='unicode', with_tail=False))
    return output_list

but with_tail=False doesn't do what I expect

I'm curious to know why you want this.  The point of something like BeautifulSoup is to let you think about the page as a tree of objects instead of a big long string.

And why do you need to split the string like that? Anyway, I don't think BS provides any way to get information about the source string. It just parses it and returns the parsed objects.

Right.  If you want to do plain string parsing, then BeautifulSoup is not the right package for you.

@TimRoberts do you know of a good HTML parsing library I could use?

But you're not interested in the "HTML-ness" of the data.  If you want to treat it like text, then just use regular expressions.  However, with BeautifulSoup, you can fetch the objects before and after your target.  Isn't that what you really want?  You just  need to think about objects, not strings.

@TimRoberts How do you fetch the objects before and after the <br> in <p>Hello<br>there</p> ?

If you find the containing <p> tag, you can just do for part in tag:.  You'll get three items: the before, the <br>, and the after.

@TimRoberts I think that will only return Hello and there, it won't return <p>Hello and there</p>

Find the element you want to split on, delete all previous elements and the element itself. This will give you the right side of the split result.
Do the same thing (but delete all next elements) to get the left side.
from itertools import chain

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_right(soup: BeautifulSoup, tag_name: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    right = BeautifulSoup(str(soup), 'html.parser')
    right_tag = right.find(tag_name)
    if right_tag is not None:
        for parent in chain([right_tag], list(right_tag.parents)):
            for sibling in list(parent.previous_siblings):
                sibling.extract()
        right_tag.extract()
    else:
        return BeautifulSoup('', 'html.parser')
    return right


def get_left(soup: BeautifulSoup, tag_name: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    left = BeautifulSoup(str(soup), 'html.parser')
    left_tag = left.find(tag_name)
    if left_tag is not None:
        for parent in chain([left_tag], list(left_tag.parents)):
            for sibling in list(parent.next_siblings):
                sibling.extract()
        left_tag.extract()
    return left


def split(input_str: str, tag_name: str) -> list[str]:
    right = BeautifulSoup(input_str, 'html.parser')
    output = []
    while len(right):
        left = get_left(right, tag_name)
        output.append(str(left))
        right = get_right(right, tag_name)
    return output

>>> split('hello<br    >there', 'br')
['hello', 'there']
>>> split('start<div id="d71">text1<br data-i="1">text2<br>text3</div>end', 'br')
['start<div id="d71">text1</div>', '<div id="d71">text2</div>', '<div id="d71">text3</div>end']
>>> split('<br>there<br>', 'br')
['', 'there', '']
>>> split('there', 'br')
['there']


Using lxml as HTML parser
let's say the doc fragment is
<div id="d71">text1<br/>text2<br/>text3</div>

Look for all text nodes within the div element
from lxml import html
doc = html.parse('/home/lmc/tmp/test.html')

d71out = []
d71nodes = doc.xpath('//div[@id="d71"]/descendant-or-self::*')

# first found element is the parent
attr_txt = ' '.join([f'{k}="{v}"' for k,v in d71nodes[0].attrib.items()])
# first ouput element with parent start tag + attributes + text
d71out.append(f'<{d71nodes[0].tag} {attr_txt}>{d71nodes[0].text}')

for ele in d71nodes[1:]:
    if ele.text is not None:
        d71out.append(ele.text)
    if ele.tail is not None:
        d71out.append(ele.tail)

d71out[-1] += f'</{d71nodes[0].tag}>'

print(d71out)

The result can be constructed as OP expects in this simple case but could get hard to do with more complex trees specially if html indentation needs to be preserved.
['<div id="d71">text1', 'text2', 'text3</div>']

This sample illustrates the problem when the tree is not that simple
    <div id="d72">text1
        <span>text2a <br/> tail1</span>tail2
        <span>text3
        </span>tail3
    </div>

tail2 appears before tail1
['<div id="d72">text1\n        ', 'text2a ', 'tail2\n        ', ' tail1', 'text3\n        ', 'tail3\n    </div>']

I'm interested in using lxml, but this not the output I'm after for that input string; I would like it to output ['<div id="d71">text1', 'text2', 'text3</div>']

@Nils updated answer with first and last element reconstructed from found elements.

Here is an example:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<p>one<br>two</p>
<p>two<br>three</p>
"""

page = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

for t in page.find_all('p'):
    print("Got this:", t)
    for u in t:
        print(u)

Output:
Got this: <p>one<br/>two</p>
one
<br/>
two
Got this: <p>two<br/>three</p>
two
<br/>
three

I think it should be pretty clear how to fetch the before and after from this.

So actually what I would want outputted for that input text is <p>one and two</p><p>two<br>three</p>; or <p>one, two</p><p>two, three</p>; with or without the input text's newlines

@mzjn how could I improve my question?

In this particular case, we KNOW that everything in that inner loop is inside of a <p> tag, because I did a find_all.  Thus, we have all the information you need.
